# WPF + visual studio 2010 premium - frequent crashes

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wpf

using it on 3 different machines, and only my work machine experiences these crashes..

it is running:

- win 7 Enterprise
- xeon X5355 2.66Ghz, 2660 Mhz, 4Core, 4Logical
- 8 gig ram (available phys memory:
  3.52 gb)
- nvidia quardo nvs 285, nvdidia
  quadro nvs 290
- 4 monitors
- visual studio 2010 premium
  4.0.30319 RTMRel

the crashes usually just make me restart vs, however, on some occasions they freeze the machine completely and require hard boot.

not seeing much in event viewer

looking for some troubleshooting ideas to narrow this down..

UPDATE

ok so switching over the video card turned out to do the trick.. something about it was not playing nice with WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting the user option files for the projects and solution. Delete all obj and bin folders. More importantly, clear out the temporary files.

Using Visual Studio 2008 temporary files, for example:

- ("%APPDATA%") & "\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ProjectAssemblies")
- ("%USERPROFILE%") & "\Local Settings\Application Data\ApplicationHistory")
- ("%USERPROFILE%") & "\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ProjectAssemblies")
- ("%WINDIR%") & "\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files")